# Cant start mysql

Tags: 20.04, mysql, mariadb

When i try to run

```
sudo service mysql start
```

it just kinda "loads" no output or nothing.

nothing is shown in the error logs.

```
sudo service mysql status  
 mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.32 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2022-04-13 11:43:40 CEST; 2min 39s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 2247 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2258 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2259 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, stat>
   Main PID: 2307 (mysqld)
      Tasks: 33 (limit: 1103)
     Memory: 352.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─2307 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Apr 13 11:43:40 servername systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.32 database server...
Apr 13 11:43:40 servername mysqld[2307]: 2022-04-13 11:43:40 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.32-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 2307 ...
```

Doing it without sudo gives the same result

EDIT

So it seemes that stuff didnt work properly after all but it got solved by doing the following

There was a corrupted profile i  `/etc/apparmor.d (usr.sbin.mysqld)`

```
echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" > /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

After that a restart of the service was made and everything seems to be back to normal

Comment: Hello. Are you sure you need to use sudo to start the app? Have you tried it without?

Comment: Tried just now and it just says AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE and same state when it just is stuck

Comment: You may want to edit the question and add it happens with and without using sudo.

Comment: This is normal behavior.  You started mysql (actually MariaDB in this case) server.  It sits there and waits for commands to be processed,  You will need a client program for that (be it GUI or not).  You probably want to start `mysql -uroot -p` to be able to start mysql commands.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen do i just run that command ? And when it asks for a password what password is that ?

Comment: Yes, just run the command.  Normally, the root password has been set when configuring the MariaDB database.  If you do not remember it, please refer to the numerous posts about how to do that.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen ill try that and get back to you with the outcome. Need to find the password as it seems like it wasn't any of the password i posses

Comment: More informative logs can be found in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. This should let you know *exactly* what the problem is. As for connecting to the database as root, be sure to do it like this: `sudo mysql`. That's all there is to it. Only `sudo` can connect to MySQL (or MariaDB) as `root`.

Comment: @matigo: Just using mysql is enough.  The `root` of mysql is not the `root` of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

so it seemes that stuff didnt work properly after all but it got solved by doing the following

There was a corrupted profile in `/etc/apparmor.d (usr.sbin.mysqld)`

```
echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" > /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

After that a restart of the service was made and everything seems to be back to normal